# Authorization with using Windows Account

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App (c#) I have own authorization mechanism:

1. User past their account name / password and sent it to server.
2. Server generate unique token and returns it to user.
3. For all next requests user used this token.

Now I'm in trying to make authorization with using only Windows Account.
MSDN [provide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx) `UserInformation class` and I can get `name for the user account` or `domain name for the user`. But I thing this is not enough for my authorization scheme.

Also method `GetSessionInitiationProtocolUriAsync` looks very interesting, but I don't know how correct use such `Uri` for authorization.

How I can use Windows Account for authorization in my application?
note: I'm interested in both situation: when user inside domain or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing Authorization and Authentication, Windows Account is to identify the user (Authentication), after you know ho he is than you grant him appropriate access (Authorization). Any case what you are looking for is Claims Based Authentication. I Never used it on windows store apps so I wont post a reply as it might be different.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid thanks for your comment. I think I will wait someone, who has experience in usage Claims Based Authentication in Windows Store Apps.

Comment: In my windows store app, I'm logging in users using their Microsoft account through Live SDK. It will generate a unique token for each user, using which the client application registers with my server. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 5):

There is numerous was to implement this but if you want to keep it simple and own the process you could implement your own authentication method which on a successful authentication you could build a hash value from their password and secret salt which could be returned to the user as a cookie etc. which you use to validate on every request there after.

On regards to authorisation you can implement your own or use a role based provider linked to the local machine group or active directory by using the classes below or just using the plain old [RoleProviders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could implement your own method of authentication using the method described below or using the [Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/907hb5w9(v=vs.100).aspx) and Authorisation provider for ASP.Net (if your server runs on .net). Basically the [Asp.Net Membership and role Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider). However the method detailed below will allow you to access and modify roles and other information about the user too.

In .Net 3.5+ there is a new namespace called [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).

Snippet from MSDN

> The System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace provides
>   uniform access and manipulation of user, computer, and group security
>   principals across the multiple principal stores: Active Directory
>   Domain Services (AD DS), Active Directory Lightweight Directory
>   Services (AD LDS), and Machine SAM (MSAM).
>
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement manages directory objects
>   independent of the System.DirectoryServices namespace. Managed
>   directory services applications can take advantage of the
>   AccountManagement API to simplify management of user, computer and
>   group principals. Solutions that previously required intricate
>   knowledge of the store or lengthy code, such as finding all groups to
>   which a user belongs, are accomplished in a few lines of code with the
>   AccountManagement API.

You can easily authenticate a user credential on AD using the code below:

```
 bool valid = false;
 using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
 {
     valid = context.ValidateCredentials( username, password );
 }
```

If you want to validate using a local machine account you can change the constructor too:

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)
```

You can check the documentation for other options and additionally this will let you get all sort of information from the store like membership etc.

The new namespace was Microsoft attempt to simplify DirectoryServices which I think was successful but if you want even more control you could use the DirectoryServices classes but that would increase the complexity of the solution.

I hope this helps if you require further information or you think it is not quite what you are looking for let me know I will endeavour to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm afraid you're confusing authentication and authorization.
**Authentication** - proving a user's identity (like me presenting an ID when going to the bank)
**Authorization** - deciding whether an identity is allowed to perform some action (like whether the client "Nitz" can drain account #44422).

A Microsoft account can only provide you with **authentication** - the client will use some scheme to prove to your server that it belongs to *bla@microsoft.com*, and it's up to you to decide if it is allowed to do stuff in your application (authorization).
With domain accounts, you can use domain group membership to help with your authorization (it's even common in windows server applications), which you usually get "for free" with the user's authentication token.

Assuming I understood you correctly and you're indeed looking for authentication, you have to provide two behaviors - one for using domain authentication and  one for Microsoft account authentication. This is because libraries and communication protocols are very different between the two.

### Providing authentication

Using this [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-single-sign-on/) from Microsoft Azure's guys, you can set up a sample application / website combination that utilizes Microsoft account authentication.

To use domain authentication (kerberos / NTLM), you can follow [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2012/10/13/how-to-use-credentialcache-defaultnetworkcredentials-with-windows-store-apps.aspx) and simply enable "integrated windows authentication" in your web site/service (I'm assuming it's IIS). If you're new to enteprise authentication, I'll shortly say that when set up properly (no time differences, AD issues etc.), the authentication is seamless. If there are issues, fall back to a simple "hello world" website and test it from Internet Explorer.

For each scenario, you best create a "hello world" method returning the user's authentication information, to make sure you got it right.

### Providing authorization

with each authentication method you end up with a unique ID (Microsoft account: `UserId`. Domain accounts: `SID`). Your logic should translate this info to a set of permissions - e.g. Maintaining a table that has the ID in one column, and `isAdmin` in another. Your application should consult this logic when deciding whether to allow or deny an action from a client.

### Combining enterprise and public

Since the methods to authenticate public users are different from the ones used for enterprise users, you'll probably end up with different IDs for the same user when connected from different methods (e.g. `DOMAIN\bla` and `bla.blason@outlook.com`). If you intend to provide both authentication methods at the same time, you have to account for that (for example, by creating a "user" table that has one column for Microsoft account IDs, and one for Domain SIDs). It usually makes little sense to provide both authentication methods at the same time, but it's your app.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

Once i had the similar situation, (A client app need to connect to server with few identity credentials. after the custom authentication , a token will be grant for the client with few claims, then each client request will be validated against the given token) , if you are in something like this, consider this link, it helped me to solve the issue.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Note: you can implement custom authentication, and authorization by extending claimsAuthenticationManager and Claimsauthorizationmanager respectively

Comment: I'm sorry, but ClaimsAuthenticationManager - is no supported in Windows Store Apps. Thanks for help.